# How do I preselect an option in jQuery selectmenu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery UI `selectmenu` which is dynamically populated hence I have no option to set "selected" attribute in one of the options.

```
for (var i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) 
{
$("#ListID").append($("<option></option>").val(Data[i].ColorName).html(Data[i].ColorName));
}
```

Also, I'v tried various other methods for setting the values as selected such as:

1. `$('#ListID').val(Data[0].ColorName);` didn't work
2. `$("#ListID[value='" + Data[0].ColorName + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');` didn't work
3. `$('#ListID').selectmenu("refresh");` <=this shows the last value but still it isn't selected as on submit it shows blank value

So, How should I pre-select the option in the `selectmenu` to the first i.e 0th element of the array

The problem is it always forces the user to select an option from the drop down which else it shows blank value on submit which shouldn't be the case since I am pre-selecting one value.

Comment: Method #1 works for me, see https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/51zhf0kv/5/

Comment: Method #3 also works: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/51zhf0kv/6/

Comment: In #2, the selector should be `$("#ListID option[value='" + Data[0].ColorName + "']")`

Comment: Yes these methods are working now, but the problem is if I don't select any option and click submit, it forces me to select an option which I don't want as there is one value which is pre-selected

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) 
{
   $("#ListID").append("<option value='"+Data[i].ColorName+"' "+(i == 0 ? "selected":"")+">"+Data[i].ColorName+"</option>");
}
```

or

```
for (var i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) 
{
    $("#ListID").append($("<option "+(i == 0 ? "selected":"")+"></option>").val(Data[i].ColorName).html(Data[i].ColorName));
}
```

> Use **selected** on option you want to be selected.

Comment: are you sure this won't make all options as selected? Because I thought of doing this but then thought it would make all selected..

Comment: Is there any function for form validation on form submit that you wrote? If yes please share.

Comment: Basically I am developing form in asp.net mvc, so I am using the usual ModelState.IsValid and have made the drop down select list as required..

Comment: Try disabling ViewState property for select control. Actaully .net will not accept any changes or modification with such controls like select. It will accept it back only in state how it is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Just i have made a simple selection by making an array of colors, please get your idea from here and let me know if it works.

```js
 $("#ListID").selectmenu();
var Data = [{ColorName:"orange"},{ColorName:"blue"},{ColorName:"green"},{ColorName:"red"}];
var selected = "blue";
for (var i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) 
{
var select = '';
if(selected==Data[i].ColorName){
   select = "selected=selected";
}
$("#ListID").append($("<option "+select+"></option>").val(Data[i].ColorName).html(Data[i].ColorName));
}
$("#ListID").selectmenu("refresh");
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  

<select id="ListID">

</select>
```

Comment: `$("#speed")` should be `$("#ListID")`

Comment: Now nothing shows, you need `$("#ListID").selectmenu("refresh");` at the end to pick up the changes.

Answer (score 0):

> Let's try on this select.

```
<select id="cars">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

We want to select mercedes in jquery dynamically for example.

```
$("#cars option[value='mercedes']").prop('selected', true);
```

> option[value=''] is a selector.

Jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/onurgule/t4obc56s/

jQuery UI fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/onurgule/p44mta9e/

Comment: You're not using jQuery UI Selectmenu widget.